# Java method File::getName works differently using different slashes

Tags: java, filenames

I just recognized that the Java method "File::getName" works differently, when the file was instantiated using different slashes.

Is it a bug or a feature?

And which method would always return a short version?

Thanks for your help...

```
import java.io.*;

public class IsItABugOrAFeature{

    public static void main(String []args){
       File f1 = new File("C:/Hello/AnotherFolder/The File Name.PDF");
       System.out.println(f1.getName());
       // returns "The File Name.PDF"

       // now switch the slashes

       File f2 = new File("C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF");
       System.out.println(f2.getName());    
       // returns "C:\Hello\AnotherFolder\The File Name.PDF"
     }
}
```

Comment: It just happens on unix systems, because the backslash is not a supported directory separator and it can be used in file names (i.e. you can have a file named `C:\Hello\AnotherFolder\The File Name.PDF` - check [here](http://tpcg.io/l6Gz5T)). In windows, you get `The File Name.PDF` two times, because both slash and backslash are treated as directory separator.

Comment: Are you indeed running this code on a non-Windows platform, using a Windows path? Kudoos for BackSlash spotting this.

Comment: Forgive me for saying this, but playing by the rules instead of gaming them, and simply using the platform’s file separator, will make this a non-issue.  For instance, `Paths.get("C:", "Hello", "AnotherFolder", "The File Name.PDF")`, or `new File("C:" + File.separator + "Hello" + File.separator + "AnotherFolder" + File.separator + "The File Name.PDF"`.  (Or course, `"C:"` has no special meaning on non-Windows systems.)

Comment: I used a java online compiler with a short snippet from my windows project. 
Thanks for your help.